# Issue when using iterative loops inside recursive methods

Tags: java, loops, recursion

Hey I was making a method that uses recursion inside for loops, and for some reason the for loops never iterated... Here is an example of what i was doing but with simpler code. The code never executes past the return statement in the for loop. The program exits with state 0.

```
public static int print (int index, String num) throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("FILE.out")));
    if(index == 6)
    {
        out.println(num);
        return 5;
    }
    else
    {   
        String tempName = num;
        int i = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {           
            tempName = num;             
            tempName = num + Integer.toString(i);
            System.out.println("Num: " + num + " Index: " + index + " i: " + i);
            return print((index + 1), num);    
        }
    }
    if(index == 0)
        out.close();
    return 5;   
}
```

The console prints:

> Num:  Index: 0 i: 0
>
> Num: 0 Index: 1 i: 0
>
> Num: 00 Index: 2 i: 0

and the file FILE.out is empty.

Comment: `return print((index + 1), num);` you return in the very first iteration of the loop. And you probably intended to pass `tempName` to the recursive call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "return" keyword exits the entire method. The code inside a method that is beyond the point of a return statement will not execute. It doesn't matter what block of code it is inside. You could be inside a number of nested loops, and when return is called, all of the loops will stop immediately and you will exit the method. In your case you call "return print" which tells the code to start another call to the print method, but this calling method exits immediately after receiving the result and does not continue the for loop or any of the code beneath it.

Answer (score 2):

You return in the first iteration.

Solution: don't use return at this line:

```
return print((index + 1), num);
```

As its not possible to guess what your initial intention was, its hard to give an answer that will really improve your problem.

Comment: ok thanks, i guess i need to think of a better way to fix my problem...

Comment: user2403319, you can make the recursive call without using return:

    print((index+1), num);

Perhaps the solution is to modify the inside of the for loop to this statement, then add a return statement integer after the loop.

Comment: Thanks Scott, this is what i needed to do, i realized this then saw your comment. I was under the wrong mindset with using return.

Comment: @user2403319 Please mark the most helpful answer as the correct one to complete this question (the hook under the number)